# Efficient UDF to check formulae consistency in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

For financial modelling we often come across with the problem that we need to check array of formulas for being consistent (i.e. nobody put hard-coded values into array of formulas or adjusted formula for specific periods). Using array functions is not an option in our working environment.

I have tried to come up with a user-defined function that would check the consistency. However it is very slow and makes working in a 1-2 thousand line financial model simply impossible due to lag caused.

Can you please help me with ideas how to check the consistency efficiently or highlight inefficiencies in my code?

```
Public Function isConsistent(ByRef range_to_check As Range, Optional ByVal R1C1 As Boolean = False)
'
' Check if all formulae in range_to_check are consistent
' To check R1C1 formula, pass True as second parameter
'
'

    ' Get array of formulas: either normal formula or R1C1 depending on inputs
    If R1C1 = True Then
        formulae = range_to_check.FormulaR1C1
    Else
        formulae = range_to_check.Formula
    End If

    ' Check every formula in array
    ' If at least one formula in array does not match, return False
    If IsArray(formulae) Then
        firstFormula = formulae(1, 1)
        For Each f In formulae
            If f <> firstFormula Then
                isConsistent = False
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next f
    End If

    ' If test passed, return True
    isConsistent = True

End Function
```

Comment: Very possibly a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) question.

Comment: Something tells me that the issue is not this UDF.  Do you use a lot of volatile functions (OFFSET,INDIRECT,NOW,...)?

Comment: Or do you have other UDFs, Events?

Comment: Something tells me that `formulae = range_to_check.Formula` creates a huge array. This step could be time consuming. Also, the `For each` is slower than just indexing the array. So: operate directly on the cells in stead of creating the array and use indexing of the cells.

Comment: Looping an array is quicker than looping the range itself.  Every time vba calls the worksheet it slows down the code.  Loading the array is quick.  But I agree that one should use a regular `For i = 1 to ...` loop when using arrays instead of `for each`  the regular for will be quicker. @PaulOgilvie

Comment: @ScottCraner That was the first thing I have done to the model when I got it - removed all volatile functions to avoid unnecessary calculations. Definitely will try For i = 1 to .... Thank you

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Thank you for the comment. I have tried to loop through the range by loading formula of one cell at a time. In my implementation, it took significantly more time than loading an array of formulas

Comment: Have you check for `Worksheet_calculate' events?

Comment: Or other UDF that may be volatile.

Comment: @ScottCraner I do not use any other UDFs in this model, so this should not be an issue. As for 'Worksheet_calculate' event, I am quite confident, there is nothing there now. What exactly do you think I should look at in terms of this event?

Comment: I am just spit balling.  To me you cannot get this UDF any more efficient and the lag must be somewhere else.

Comment: Just to be clear, you only have this in one cell, right?

Comment: @Comintern I have this function in one cell for every line of the model. The whole idea of the function is to make sure that formulas in every row of the model are consistent

Comment: So why are you making sure it's an array and checking every cell in the range? You're checking the Cartesian product of cells on the worksheet?

Comment: @Comintern technically speaking, you're right it is probably better to use array formulas for the purpose, however it has two significant limitations, namely: (1) in financial models with complicated taxation rules they may work extremely slow (magnitude of 1-2 orders slower), (2) in business environment one have to make sure that models can be read by other users and array formulas are a complicated matter for most people - therefore the model becomes untransferrable.
Not sure I understand how Cartesian product applies to the problem.

Comment: I have tested the suggested to substitute 'for each ' loop to 'for i = 1 to ' loop. Interestingly enough 'for each' loop is slightly faster than 'for i = 1 to ' option in Excel environment.